# Loading new data onto a page without reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, delayed-execution

I'm doing a high-level spec on an ASP.Net page which may have some delayed data presented.

When the page loads, the initial data presented will originate from a local database (which will be fast in presenting).  What I want is a separate process to go out and look for updated data (from whatever other services I have).  This is more time consuming, but the idea is to present data, then if newer data is found, append this, on the fly to the top of the existing page.

I would like some recommendations on how to accomplish this.

The tech scope for this is ASP.Net 4.0, C# MVC3 and HTML5.

Thanks.

Comment: The term you're looking for is AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AJAX with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is a good way to achieve this. So for example you could put a content placeholder div on your markup:

```
<div id="result" data-remote-url="@Url.Action("Load", "SomeController")"></div>
```

and then once the DOM is loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#result').data('remote-url'),
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // TODO: you could show an AJAX loading spinner
            // to indicate to the user that there is an ongoing
            // operation so that he doesn't run out of patience
        },
        complete: function() {
            // this will be executed no matter whether the AJAX request
            // succeeds or fails => you could hide the spinner here
        },
        success: function(result) {
            // In case of success update the corresponding div with
            // the results returned by the controller action
            $('#result').html(result);
        },
        error: function() {
            // something went wrong => inform the user 
            // in the gentler possible manner and remember
            // that he spent some of his precious time waiting 
            // for those results
        }
    });
});
```

where the Load controller action will take care of communicating with the remote services and return a partial view containing the data:

```
public ActionResult Load()
{
    var model = ... go ahead and fetch the model from the remote service
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Now if this *fetching* of data is I/O intensive you could take advantage of [asynchronous controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx) an I/O Completion Ports which will avoid you jeopardizing worker threads during the lengthy operation of fetching data from a remote source.